# Node.js Why such a sequence of output to the console?

Tags: node.js, fs, cryptojs

**Why is there such a sequence in the console:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vi6Rm.png)

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const startDate = Date.now();
const invokeHttpRequest = () => {
    https.request('https://www.google.com', res => {
        res.on('data', () => {});
        res.on('end', () => {
            console.log('HTTP returns data', Date.now() - startDate)
        });
    })
        .end();
}
const invokeHash = () => {
    crypto.pbkdf2('test', 'test2', 100000, 512, 'sha512' , () => {
        console.log('crypto:', Date.now() - startDate);
    });
}
invokeHttpRequest();
invokeHash();
invokeHash();
invokeHash();
invokeHash();
fs.readFile('index.js', 'utf-8', () => {
    console.log('FS:', Date.now() - startDate);
});
```

I want to know how the loop works and why is there such a sequence in the console:

1. HTTP returns data
2. crypto
3. FS
4. crypto
5. crypto
6. crypto

Why exactly did FS skip crypto and take the second thread and not the last one

Comment: Please include the output as text, rather than image. And please make clear which part of the output sequence is unexpected for you.

Comment: I have updated the question description

Answer (score 0):

Node.js is asynchronous, in fact it parralelize task.

Thus, when you call 4 times `invokeHash` calls are made before readfile, but `invokeHash` take time to execute and then `invokeHash` function return after readfile.

If you need to execute readfile after `invokeHash` calls, you should implement a callback or a promise in `invokeHash` function. And then execute readfil when all `invokeHash` function returns.

Comment: Yes, but why is the console output like this: 
-HTTP returns data
-crypto
-FS
-crypto
-crypto
-crypto

Comment: That's exactly what i explain. Your http requestion end before the others, and then console is before the others. Try we a website that is not performant and the console order will change.